# evaluate an "implicit" function

Tags: function-construction

I would like to know if it is possible to define a function for a function with an undefined variable, for example,

```
f = a*x+b*y+c*z
g[a_,b_,c_]:= f
```

If I evaluate g, f remains unchanged. The point is that I do not want to define "f" like `f[a_,b_,c_]:=a*x+b*y+c*z`. How can I create the function g, in order to evaluate f?.

Thanks

Comment: `g[a_,b_,c_]= f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me (Mathematica Student 12.1)

```
f = a*x+b*y+c*z
g[a_,b_,c_]= f
```

Just remove the `:` at the attribution to `g`

Comment: thank so much :D